# Combine data from two SQL tables to create new entry in another table

Tags: sql

I have three SQL tables as below, the first one named 'repairparts':

```
repairparts
-----------------------------------
ID    Part         Quantity
1     AAA1000      1
2     AAB1000      1
3     AAC1000      1
```

And the second named 'partslist':

```
partslist
------------------------------------
Part       Price
AAA1000    1.50
AAB1000    3.00
AAC1000    2.00
```

Now with only being given the ID value of '1', I want to be able to take the part number, and quantity from the first table named 'repairparts' linked to that ID, and combine that with the price of the same part number in the second table named 'partslist', and insert those four piece of data in to the third table named 'estimateparts'.

So the outcome would be this being inserted into the table named 'estimateparts':

```
estimateparts
-----------------------------------
ID   Part       Quantity    Price
1    AAA1000   1           1.50
```

I've read that I should use the UNION function and have tried the following, but it does nothing:

```
INSERT INTO estimateparts (ID, Part, Quantity, Price) 
SELECT ID, Part, Quantity FROM repairparts WHERE ID='1' 
UNION SELECT Price FROM partslist WHERE Part=repairparts.Part
```

Really appreciate any advice that can be given.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't copy data from table to table. Create a view instead, it will always be up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a simple join, if I'm not missing something:

```
select rp.id, rp.part, rp.quantity, pl.price
from repairparts rp join
     partslist pl
     on rp.part = pl.part
where rp.id = 1;
```